# How to search for an answer I voted for?

Tags: support, search, up-votes, recent-activity

I voted for an answer, but forgot to mark that question as a favorite.

I don't remember:

- the user who asked the question
- the user who answered the question
- the question's title

The only thing I remember is that I voted the accepted answer.

How can I find it again?

Comment: You can find all the posts that you have upvoted, in your profile's "votes" section

Comment: A related feature request: [Search by keyword for answer / question I upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224344).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427849/zey) -> click on [*votes*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427849/zey?tab=votes) tab -> click on [*upvotes*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427849/zey?tab=votes&sort=upvote) (assuming you upvoted that answer)

Here you will get the list of posts you have upvoted.

Comment: My list is too large, can'e we search by keyword?

Comment: @cirosantilli - Unfortunately we can't. This is the only option we have.

Comment: OK! Clearer feature request at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224344/search-by-keyword-for-answer-question-i-upvoted

Comment: I am not able to see "Upvotes" menu in my profile section. I have upvoted atleast 50 questions.

Comment: In profile->votes tab, where is the upvotes section

Comment: @Unbreakable: That will be in your [*Activity*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292432/unbreakable?tab=topactivity) tab as the profile page and activity tabs are separated now.