# Search by keyword for answer / question I upvoted

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, search, up-votes

I have upvoted many questions / answers, and my `profile > votes > upvotes` has 20 pages.

I am looking for a question which I upvoted long ago because I need it again, and I only know it contains a keyword: e.g. "current".

Currently, the only way I see to do this is to go to each page and search with my browser.

I propose that we have some way to filter only the questions that have that keyword.

Possible implementations:

- an input field under `profile > votes > upvotes` (easier for newbs like me to find an use)
- a search operator similar to the one that exists for favorites `infavorites`

Related to: [How to search for an answer I voted for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178430/how-to-search-for-an-answer-i-voted-for/178432), but this makes it more precise that I want to search by keyword, which is probably not required on the other question, since he accepted the `profile > votes > upvotes` answer.

Comment: In the future when you see any question you think is good and will be helpful in the future, instead of just upvote make it [favorite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/187824) also. You can search for [favorite questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine).

Comment: @hims056 thanks! Thats a good workaround. But it would be better if I could click only once to upvote, since everything I upvote I like.

Comment: Another option is to add another advanced search operator like `hasvoted:1` that will search only posts I voted for.

Comment: Agreed. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I suspect the can of worms marked 'allow the search engine to know vote ownership' is one that will not be opened lightly...

Comment: @hims056 you're facing the same problem when you have X amount of favorites...

Comment: @AakashM search engine has access to the live database as far as I know, with votes and everything. It doesn't mean it will show this information publicly, only to the logged in user.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - or `downvoted:<userid>`!! :)

Comment: *Copy of bounty message:* If search operators like "upvoted:1" and "downvoted:1" are not too expensive to implement, they should exist. It makes perfect sense for users to search through the posts they found useful in the past. "Favorite" is not an answer: one can't favorite answers, and if one always favorites questions when voting, that in effect makes votes public. // (copied because the bounty message will be gone without trace in 7 days.)

Comment: I kind of like this idea, but (setting aside the fact that I don't know how hard this would be to implement) I am struggling to come up with a name for the operators that's super clear. `upvoted:1` and `downvoted:1` don't work because they can mean 2 things: I upvoted the post, or the post has (any) up/downvotes.

Comment: related on MSO: [How can I determine when I cast a specific upvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424692/11107541)