# Please add an option to search posts I have voted on

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, voting, search, up-votes

When I vote up questions or answers, I'm not only increase poster's reputation but also saving a link to the post in my profile — the "Votes" tab shows all posts I have voted on, so it's possible to view the posts again without searching.

But finding the needed answer is uncomfortable when the number of posts voted on is too large.

Please add an option to *search in my voted posts*.

Adding a new [advanced search option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) would be easier. But I think that a filter in the "Votes" tab will be more comfortable (at least for me). Also this filter could be used in other tabs in the profile, e.g. the "Answers" and "Questions" tabs.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Ideal solution would be adding "voted:1" advanced search operator, that will take only posts you have voted on (either up or down). You can turn this question into such a feature request. (Can be expanded to also include "upvoted:1" and "downvoted:1")

Comment: Another similar feature request: [Search by keyword for answer / question I upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224344)

Answer (score 5):

No. There is not. Votes are not meant as a way to find posts back (although I understand that might not be the main reason you vote). The entire UI around it is just not built to work the way you want. The favorites tab has more sorting capabilities already and fits the purpose better. (They are public too, so you can query SEDE to get them out)

I like the suggestion from [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/), which he did in [a comment on your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272801/can-i-navigate-in-my-votes/272844#comment885995_272801):

> Ideal solution would be adding "voted:1" advanced search operator, that will take only posts you have voted on (either up or down).

The benefit of this is that it doesn't bloat the UI with a lot of buttons only a few users really use, but it is still very accessible and easy to use. (Try to search now for [`user:me deleted:1`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1) for example to see how it could work)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

Votes are always sorted in the order they were cast so that is the only way to sort your votes. It would be wise to try to remember the question name or the time you cast the vote to save time. To save more time, try using one of two sub-sections of the <kbd>votes</kbd> tab: <kbd>upvotes</kbd> and <kbd>downvotes</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, I know about ```upvotes``` and ```downvotes``` tabs, but I wrote about uncomfortable searching - too many votes are paginates, and manual searching may be too long and in titles only